# gCloud Increase vCPU and Memory

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have a gCloud Compute Engine instance, with 4 vCPUs and 16GB Ram, i need increase these parameteres, my instance is a 'e2-standard-4'.
How i can increase this?
It is possibly with no down time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement, and used the following steps, and it worked, with very little down-time (less than a minute, but DNS propagation meant web access was down for ~10 min), but I've only had the one experience, so don't trust my blindly.

First, make a snapshot of your VM.

- Snapshots > Create Snapshot > Choose your VM for Source disk

Next, create a new instance, with the better specs.

- For "Boot disk", choose the Snapshots tab, and choose your snapshot.

That should do it. You'll have a VM that acts exactly like your old VM, but beefier. I had web access, so I had to change my domain DNS settings, but HTTPS continued to work once they propagated.

If anything's unclear, let me know and I can flesh it out. If not, I hope that gets you on the right path.